# Calculate the probability density function of two independent random variables: (R^3 + r^3)^(1/3)

Tags: probability

Random variables R and r are independent, both of them are uniform distributed and greater than zero. R distributes in (a,b), r in (c,d). I tried to solve the probability density function of (R^3 + r^3)^(1/3), but I couldn't figure it out. so any one can help me out?

Question Update: c > a > 0, a + t = b , c + t = d, t > 0, c - a => t

Comment: @wolfies There is no problem taking the cube root of a negative number.

Comment: @wolfies That is not true. $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ is a well-defined map  $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @wolfies Observe $(-2)^3 = -8$, hence $(-8)^{1/3} = -2$. Taking roots of negatives is fine as long as you are looking for an odd power.

Comment: Using $R$ and $r$ to denote two different variables is highly inappropriate notation, since capitals usually denote random variables, and lower case specific instances of the same variable. You also likely need to put some constraints on the domain of support --- or specify that you are restricting the solution to just 1 of the 3 solutions (presumably the real one).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing this one step at a time.

First let's find the CDFs and densities of $R^3$ and $r^3$:
$$F_{R^3}(x)=P(R^3 \leq x) = P(R \leq x^{1/3}) = \int_{-\infty}^{x^{1/3}}\frac{1}{b-a}1_{a \leq t^{1/3} \leq b} \ dt = \begin{cases}0 & x < a^3 \\ \frac{x^{1/3}-a}{b-a}  & a^3\leq x\leq b^3 \\ 1 & x>b^3\end{cases}$$
so 
$$f_{R^3}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_{R^3}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<a^3, x>b^3 \\ \frac{1}{3(b-a)}x^{-2/3}& a^3 \leq x \leq b^3 \end{cases}.$$
Similarly you can find $F_{r^3}(x)$ and $f_{r^3}(x)$.

Then you can find the density of the sum $R^3+r^3$ using the fact that $R^3$ and $r^3$ are independent:
$$f_{R^3+r^3}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{R^3}(x-t)f_{r^3}(t) \ dt.$$
From that you can find $F_{R^3+r^3}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_{R^3+r^3}(t) \ dt$. Finally, from that you can find 
$$F_{(R^3+r^3)^{1/3}}(x) = P((R^3+r^3)^{1/3} \leq x) = P(R^3+r^3 \leq x^3)=F_{R^3+r^3}(x^3)$$
and 
$$f_{(R^3+r^3)^{1/3}}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_{(R^3+r^3)^{1/3}}(x).$$

Comment: ... which yields?

Comment: @wolfies The point of answers on Math Stack Exchange are to help the OP understand the problem and solve it themselves. It was completely intentional that I only explicitly wrote out $F_{R^3}(x)$ and $f_{R^3}(x)$. I am not going to solve OP's problem for them.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't aware that this was a homework help site. I also don't think this is a homework question.

Comment: thank you so much. this is not a homework, I encountered this question in my research. I know the procedure of solving this question, but to me the most difficult part is the complicated integration. i turn to mathematica, but it can not yield explicit expression.

Comment: Do you know anything about $a,b,c,d$ besides $a<b$ and $c<d$? Are they nonnegative? Can $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ overlap?

Comment: thank you. a, b, c and d are all positive, (a, b) and (c, d) do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \sim \text{Uniform}(a,b)$ be independent of $Y \sim \text{Uniform}(c,d)$.

We seek the pdf of $Z = X^3 + Y^3$ ... and then that of $Z^{1/3}$

The problem is quite messy to compute, even if $a>0$ and $b>0$ (which I assume below). User kccu has set out a method to proceed - that involves finding the cdf of very complicated functions, and I don't think it will yield a tractable form.

Different solutions will apply depending on the relation of the parameters. To avoid a lengthy answer, I shall summarise  the general solution:

---

**Case 1:**   $\quad \text{if } a^3 + d^3 = b^3 + c^3$, then the pdf of $Z$ is:

[image]

---

**Case 2:**   $\quad \text{if } a^3 + d^3 > b^3 + c^3$, then the pdf of $Z$ is:

[image]

---

**Case 3:**   $\quad \text{if } a^3 + d^3 < b^3 + c^3$, then the pdf of $Z$ is:

[image]

---

One can click on each pdf above, to view it in more detail.

For each case, one can then transform $Z \rightarrow Z^{1/3}$ which should comparatively be the easier step.

Comment: thank you so much for your work. the solution looks quite complicated, so I guess the CDF related to the random variables is far complicated. again, thank you so much.

Comment: One more question, when you handle this problem did you know the CDF of  random variable Z? Because CDF is more important to me.